# Google Play In-App Review API. How to check if the user has rated the app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play

[image]
Is it possible to check if the user has rated the app using In-App Review API? (pressed the Submit button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no way to find out whether user has rated the using google In-App review API . Please refer [Launch the in-app review flow](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#launch-review-flow)